# ¿Como centrar una imagen y tome el mayor tamaño posible?

Tags: html, css3

Tengo el conocimiento básico en `css` e intentado centrar dichas imágenes dentro de un `div` para dar aspecto a tarjetas, pero no logro posicionar en el centro las imágenes. aquí el código que e intentado, lo que esta comentado es lo ultimo que intente realizar.

```css
.container-img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(59, 58, 58, 1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container-img img{
    width:100%;
    /* display: block; */
    /* margin: auto auto; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* object-fit: contain; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='container-img'>
        <img src="https://example.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/EXAMPLE-LOGO-BLACK.png" alt='ejemplo' />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar:

```
.container-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Lo que hace es tu imagen utilice todo el espacio de `.container-img` y ajuste la imagen al tamaño adecuado de acuerdo a sus dimensiones:

```css
.container-img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(59, 58, 58, 1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-img'>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
</div>
<div class='container-img'>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x208" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar esto en tu class del div

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: en caso de haberte ayudado agradeceria marcaras como aceptada mi respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Para centrar una imagen, que según entiendo la quieres verticalmente puedes utilizar [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) y alineación al centro de la siguiente forma:

```css
.container-img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(59, 58, 58, 1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container-img {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.container-img img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='container-img'>
            <img src="https://example.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/EXAMPLE-LOGO-BLACK.png" alt='ejemplo' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Saludos. ;)